# Свойства кнопок меняются в kivy

Tags: python-3.6, kivy, grid

У меня есть GridLayout, который состоит из кнопок. При нажатии на какую-либо из них, нажатая меняет цвет.

Под этим гридом у меня есть кнопка Start, при нажатии на которую все кнопки должны становиться одинаковыми, но этого не происходит. Я попробовал выводить текущий цвет каждой кнопки после нажатия на Start, но в выводе везде одинаковые значения

Вот код на python:

```py
import kivy

kivy.require('1.9.1')  # Ваша версия может отличаться

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
import numpy as np


class Field(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.rows = 5
        self.cols = 5
        self.status = ListProperty([[0 for _ in range(5)] for _ in range(5)])
        super(Field, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.buttons = [[None for _ in range(self.cols)] for _ in range(self.rows)]
        for row in range(self.rows):
            for col in range(self.cols):
                grid_entry = GridEntry(coords=(row, col))
                grid_entry.bind(on_press=self.button_pressed)
                self.add_widget(grid_entry)
                self.buttons[row][col] = grid_entry

    def button_pressed(self, button):
        x, y = button.coords
        colors = {0: (0, 1, 0, 1), 1: (1, 1, 1, 1)}
        button.background_color = colors[self.status.defaultvalue[x][y]]
        self.status.defaultvalue[x][y] ^= 1
        print(list(map(lambda x: x.background_color, self.children)))

    def get_buttons(self):
        return self.buttons

    def make_new_population(self):
        pop = np.array(self.status.defaultvalue)
        neighbors = sum([
            np.roll(np.roll(pop, -1, 1), 1, 0),
            np.roll(np.roll(pop, 1, 1), -1, 0),
            np.roll(np.roll(pop, 1, 1), 1, 0),
            np.roll(np.roll(pop, -1, 1), -1, 0),
            np.roll(pop, 1, 1),
            np.roll(pop, -1, 1),
            np.roll(pop, 1, 0),
            np.roll(pop, -1, 0)
        ])
        neighbors = (neighbors == 3) | (pop & (neighbors == 2))
        for i in range(self.rows):
            for j in range(self.cols):
                self.status.defaultvalue[i][j] = neighbors[i, j]

    def paint(self):
        print(list(map(lambda x: x.background_color, self.children)))
        self.make_new_population()
        for i in self.children:
            x, y = i.coords
            was = i.background_color
            i.background_color = (1, 1, 1, 1)
            if was != i.background_color:
                print(x, y)


class LifeGrid(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LifeGrid, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.field = Field()
        self.in_game = False

    def start(self, button):
        self.in_game = True
        self.paint()

    def paint(self):
        if self.in_game:
            self.field.paint()


class GridEntry(Button):
    coords = ListProperty([0, 0])


class LifeApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return LifeGrid()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    LifeApp().run()
```

Вот код на kivy:

```
<LifeGrid>:
    id: lifegrid
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Field:
        cols: 5
        rows: 5
    GridLayout:
        height: '50dp'
        width: self.parent.width
        size_hint: None, None
        cols: 2
        rows: 1
        row_default_width: self.parent.width // 2
        Button:
            id: start_button
            on_press: lifegrid.start(start_button)
            text: 'Start'
            font_size: '20dp'
        Button:
            id: restart_button
            on_press: lifegrid.restart(restart_button)
            text: 'Restart'
            font_size: '20dp'

<GridEntry>:
    font_size: self.height
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается, стоило до `__init__` написать `buttons = ListProperty([[None for _ in range(5)] for _ in range(5)])`, после чего

```py
for i in range(self.rows):
    for j in range(self.cols):
        self.buttons[i][j].background_color = (1, 1, 1, 1)
```

Я не понимаю, почему это так. Был бы очень благодарен тому, кто объяснит, почему я не могу просто пройтись по `children` и поменять `background_color` циклом